# Ho can i rearrange array in php

Tags: php, arrays

For example i have an array like this

```
$a=[0=>"a",1=>"b",2=>"c",3=>"d",4=>"e",5=>"f",6=>"h",7=>"h",8=>"i",9=>"j",10=>"k"];
```

what i want to do is reannge this array like below;

```
$m=[

0=>[a,b],
1=>[c,d],
2=>[e,f],
3=>[g,h],
4=>[i,j],
5=>[k]


]
```

as you see i need to devide all values in new arrays inside one array. But each sub array must be have only 2 value. Could you help me to rearrange this?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you have already tried.

Comment: Isn't this just [`array_chunk`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array-chunk).

> `array_chunk ( array $array , int $size [, bool $preserve_keys = FALSE ] ) : array`
>
> Chunks an array into arrays with **size** elements. The last chunk may contain less than **size** elements.

```
$a = [0=>"a",1=>"b",2=>"c",3=>"d",4=>"e",5=>"f",6=>"h",7=>"h",8=>"i",9=>"j",10=>"k"];
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_chunk($a,2));
```

Comment: **Side note:** Always use official documentation as canonical reference as edited by Sherif. Also, [`w3schools shouldn't really be recommended`](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4975/why-shouldnt-i-use-w3schools-as-reference)

Comment: @vivek_23 "[Today, W3Schools has largely resolved these issues and addressed the majority of the undersigned developers' concerns. For many beginners, W3Schools has structured tutorials and playgrounds that offer a decent learning experience.](https://www.w3fools.com/)" - w3fools. Please re-read the top voted answer, as it'll explain that the site is fine now.

Comment: @Peilonrayz I wouldn't still recommend as first preference over the official doc. Even they have a line saying _Do keep in mind: a more complete education will certainly include MDN and other reputable resources_

Comment: @vivek_23 A more complete education learns from anything one can get their hands on. You don't need to take everything as a slight against W3Schools.

Comment: @Peilonrayz Ok, fair enough.

Comment: There are still flaws in w3schools and official documentations, such as MDN, php.net, MSDN and others can be improved by community.

Comment: Okay next time i will check

Answer (score 0):

You can re-format those array as per your output by the following snippets.

```php
$a = [
    0  => "a",
    1  => "b",
    2  => "c",
    3  => "d",
    4  => "e",
    5  => "f",
    6  => "h",
    7  => "h",
    8  => "i",
    9  => "j",
    10 => "k"
];


$m = [];

for ( $i = 0; $i <= sizeof( $a ); $i ++ ) {
    if ( is_int( $i / 2 ) ) {
        $m[] = [ $a[ $i ], $a[ $i + 1 ] ];
    }
}

print_r( $m );
```

`$m` would be the reformmed array like this -

```
[
    0 => [ 'a', 'b' ],
    1 => [ 'c', 'd' ],
    2 => [ 'e', 'f' ],
    3 => [ 'g', 'h' ],
    4 => [ 'i', 'j' ],
    5 => [ 'k' ]
];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
// input array
$a = [0=>"a",1=>"b",2=>"c",3=>"d",4=>"e",5=>"f",6=>"h",7=>"h",8=>"i",9=>"j",10=>"k"];

// solution 1: using built in function
$a1 = array_chunk($a, 2); 

// solution 2: for loop
$count = count($a);
$a2 = [];
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i+=2) {
  $a2inner = [$a[$i]];
  if(array_key_exists($i+1, $a)) {
      $a2inner[] = $a[$i+1];
  }
  $a2[] = $a2inner;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$a = array_chunk($a,2);
```

The array_chunk() function splits an array into chunks of new arrays.

For more info, you can have a look at:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk